# Reading from file to array

Tags: c, io, fread

I am trying to read from a file. I am using fread(), but I'm unsure whether I'm going about this correctly. I want to create an array of structs and continue "f-reading" from the file into the array like so:

```
//Get size of file
struct stat st;
stat(document, &st);
int size = st.st_size;

//Create appropriate array size of structs

struct Person person[size];

for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    fread(person[j].name, 1, 16, fp); //each name is truncated to 15 bytes on the file
    fread(person[j].text, 1, 24, fp);  //text is truncated to 24 on the file
}
```

struct Person look like so:

```
struct Person {
    char name[16];
    char text[24];
};
```

Am I using fread() correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the fread function call succeeded in reading the expected number of bytes from the data stream:

```
//Get size of file
struct stat st;
int name_bytes_read, text_bytes_read; // If using C11, use size_t instead
stat(document, &st);
int size = st.st_size;


//Create appropriate array size of structs

struct Person person[size];

for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    name_bytes_read = fread(person[j].name, 1, 16, fp); //each name is truncated to 15 bytes on the file
    if (name_bytes_read != 16) { 
      fputs ("Error reading name record", stderr); 
      exit(-1);
    }
    text_bytes_read = fread(person[j].text, 1, 24, fp);  //text is truncated to 24 on the file
    if (text_bytes_read != 24) {
      fputs ("Error reading text record", stderr);
      exit(-1); }
}
```

Further reading: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Upon trying your suggestion, I do receive an error "Error reading name record"... I believe it's for the last fread() when there is nothing left to read. Am I correct? How can I fix this?

Comment: fread() can be somewhat ... brittle ... when parsing a data file this way.  You might consider using fgets() to get a line at a time, then parsing the line, perhaps with sscanf() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code given below is sufficient inside the for loop

```
fread(person[j], sizeof(struct Person), 1, fp);
```

Comment: should really be `fread(person+j,sizeof(struct Person),1,fp)` the first argument should be a pointer, and Person is not a type in C, struct Person is.

Answer (score 0):

Increment j by sizeof(struct Person) to avoid fread issue
Alternatively you can use feof to check end of file